# html5 video hover change opacity of another element

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video, video.js

So I've got a page here : http://www.ruffcuts.com.sg/work/bosch.htm among some other pages.

I'm looking to hover over the video element and then change the opacity of the grass image in front(id=plax-sphere-52 src=homehead6.png) so that the controls to the player can be seen.

But somehow it doesn't work! I've tried

```
$('#videocontain').mouseover(function() {
$('img#plax-sphere-52').css('opacity', '0.6');
});
$('#videocontain').mouseout(function() {
$('img#plax-sphere-52').css('opacity', '1');
});
```

And other similar codings, but it just doesn't work.

Could there be a conflict somewhere or I'm just simply coding it all wrong? Using http://videojs.com/ by the way.

Comment: What would you need controls for that are unaccessible behind a semi transparent image? You are trying to hover over the container not the video by the way.

Comment: sorry i'm not sure what you mean. the controls are accessible because my grass image in front is at `pointer-events:none;` so i'm able to click behind the image. also i've tried using the video's id and calling the video tag itself. to no avail :(

Comment: Are you sure this "click behind" works on touch devices as well?

Comment: hmm that's true. i've not tested that out yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see an error on your page that's breaking jQuery.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'plaxify' ruffcutsprod.js:4

$
undefined
```

Other than that I don't see an issue. You might try mousemove instead of mouseover.

Comment: hmmm. i tried calling the scripts to remove that error. but still the same. i don't think that's the problem because that page doesn't use those scripts

Comment: i stand corrected. it's working now after i add my plax and spritely plugins. strange cuz i dont use them on that page. strange also, there would still be an typeerror for another missing plugin. but still thank you so much @heff

Answer (score 0):

The `mouseover/mouseout` events bubble. Therefore, when your mouse enters the the video tag, a mouseout event fires on the container div and a mouseenter on the video div.

Therefore, when the mouse moves into the video, the mouseover fires, sets the opacity to 0.6, then the mouseout fires immediately and sets the opacity back to 1.0

Try using `mouseentter/mouseleave` events which don't bubble, or you could test that the source of the event is the wrapping div, not any elements within that div.